# export json structure to mysql

Tags: mysql, json

I have an app that uses json files to store data. I would like my app to support CMS (currently I don't know which one) thus I need a database, probably mysql. So my questions is, is it possible to automate the creation of the tables? By creation I mean just the structure of them, neither populating them nor importing the data from the json files.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is. Use this script to create tables from code:

```
CREATE [TEMPORARY] TABLE [IF NOT EXISTS] tbl_name
    (create_definition,...)
    [table_options]
    [partition_options]
```

The documentation see here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html